# Blackberry using C++ classes in QML in headless app: undefined reference to `bb::device::VibrationController::staticMetaObject'

Tags: blackberry, qml, headless

I have been weeks working on BB and had a lot of troubles. Some of them were resolved, some weren't without support from forum.
Now I have a big trouble which I cannot find answer by googling.
I am appreciated if some body can help.

Here is simple case which make big problem for me:

1. Create a headless app by using Momentics. Two projects will be generated HeadlessApp and HeadlessAppService.
   Without modification, this code run well.
2. I follow [this link](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/dev/integrating_cpp_qml/index.html#usingcclassesinqm) to use VibrationController in HeadlessAppService 
   Add below codes to main.cpp of HeadlessAppService

`#include <bb/device/VibrationController>`

`using namespace bb::device;`

then add qmlRegisterType as below

```
Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

   Application app(argc, argv);

   qmlRegisterType<VibrationController>("bb.vibrationController", 1, 0, "VibrationController");
   ApplicationUI appui;
   return Application::exec();
}
```

3. To confirm this new code, I simply right click on project, and select Build Project. 
   Bang!!! I got many error which I cannot understand. (red lines are errors)

```html
08:44:30 **** Incremental Build of configuration Device-Debug for project headlessTest ****
make -j4 Device-Debug 
make -C .//translations -f Makefile update
make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/BB-dev/momentics-workspace/headlessTest/translations'
C:/bbndk/host_10_3_1_12/win32/x86/usr/bin/lupdate headlessTest.pro
Updating 'headlessTest.ts'...
    Found 2 source text(s) (0 new and 2 already existing)
make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/BB-dev/momentics-workspace/headlessTest/translations'
make -C .//translations -f Makefile release
make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/BB-dev/momentics-workspace/headlessTest/translations'
C:/bbndk/host_10_3_1_12/win32/x86/usr/bin/lrelease headlessTest.pro
Updating 'D:/BB-dev/momentics-workspace/headlessTest/translations/headlessTest.qm'...
    Generated 0 translation(s) (0 finished and 0 unfinished)
    Ignored 2 untranslated source text(s)
make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/BB-dev/momentics-workspace/headlessTest/translations'
make -C ./arm -f Makefile debug
make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/BB-dev/momentics-workspace/headlessTest/arm'
make -f Makefile.Debug
make[2]: Entering directory 'D:/BB-dev/momentics-workspace/headlessTest/arm'
qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le -lang-c++ -Wl,-rpath-link,C:/bbndk/target_10_3_1_995/qnx6/armle-v7/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,C:/bbndk/target_10_3_1_995/qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,C:/bbndk/target_10_3_1_995/qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib/qt4/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,C:/bbndk/target_10_3_1_995/qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib/qt4/lib -o o.le-v7-g/headlessTest o.le-v7-g/.obj/applicationui.o o.le-v7-g/.obj/main.o o.le-v7-g/.obj/moc_applicationui.o    -LC:/bbndk/target_10_3_1_995/qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib/bb1 -LC:/bbndk/target_10_3_1_995/qnx6/armle-v7/lib -LC:/bbndk/target_10_3_1_995/qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib -LC:/bbndk/target_10_3_1_995/qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib/qt4/lib -LC:/bbndk/target_10_3_1_995/qnx6//usr/lib/qt4/lib -lbb -lbbsystem -lbbcascades -lQtDeclarative -lQtScript -lQtSvg -lQtSql -lsqlite3 -lz -lQtXmlPatterns -lQtGui -lQtNetwork -lsocket -lQtCore -lm -lbps 
o.le-v7-g/.obj/main.o: In function `int qmlRegisterType<bb::device::VibrationController>(char const*, int, int, char const*)':
**c:/bbndk/target_10_3_1_995/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtDeclarative/qdeclarative.h:191: undefined reference to `bb::device::VibrationController::staticMetaObject'
o.le-v7-g/.obj/main.o: In function `QDeclarativeElement':
**c:/bbndk/target_10_3_1_995/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtDeclarative/qdeclarativeprivate.h:87: undefined reference to `bb::device::VibrationController::VibrationController(QObject*)'
o.le-v7-g/.obj/main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN19QDeclarativePrivate19QDeclarativeElementIN2bb6device19VibrationControllerEEE[_ZTVN19QDeclarativePrivate19QDeclarativeElementIN2bb6device19VibrationControllerEEE]+0x8): undefined reference to `bb::device::VibrationController::metaObject() const'
o.le-v7-g/.obj/main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN19QDeclarativePrivate19QDeclarativeElementIN2bb6device19VibrationControllerEEE[_ZTVN19QDeclarativePrivate19QDeclarativeElementIN2bb6device19VibrationControllerEEE]+0xc): undefined reference to `bb::device::VibrationController::qt_metacast(char const*)'
o.le-v7-g/.obj/main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN19QDeclarativePrivate19QDeclarativeElementIN2bb6device19VibrationControllerEEE[_ZTVN19QDeclarativePrivate19QDeclarativeElementIN2bb6device19VibrationControllerEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `bb::device::VibrationController::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)'
o.le-v7-g/.obj/main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN19QDeclarativePrivate19QDeclarativeElementIN2bb6device19VibrationControllerEEE[_ZTIN19QDeclarativePrivate19QDeclarativeElementIN2bb6device19VibrationControllerEEE]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for bb::device::VibrationController'
o.le-v7-g/.obj/main.o: In function `~QDeclarativeElement':
**c:/bbndk/target_10_3_1_995/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtDeclarative/qdeclarativeprivate.h:91: undefined reference to `bb::device::VibrationController::~VibrationController()'
**c:/bbndk/target_10_3_1_995/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtDeclarative/qdeclarativeprivate.h:91: undefined reference to `bb::device::VibrationController::~VibrationController()'cc: C:/bbndk/host_10_3_1_12/win32/x86/usr/bin/ntoarm-ld caught signal 1
**    Makefile.Debug:103: recipe for target 'o.le-v7-g/headlessTest' failed
make[2]: *** [o.le-v7-g/headlessTest] Error 1make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/BB-dev/momentics-workspace/headlessTest/arm'
make[1]: *** [debug] Error 2
Makefile:50: recipe for target 'debug' failed
make: *** [Device-Debug] Error 2make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/BB-dev/momentics-workspace/headlessTest/arm'
mk/cs-base.mk:31: recipe for target 'Device-Debug' failed
08:44:31 Build Finished (took 1s.47ms)
```

The error line are marked with ** (2 stars).
I am giving up!!!
Why adding simple code can make problem? Please help me!
Many thanks!

Comment: I found reason. I forgot adding LIBS += -lbbdevice to pro file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found reason. I forgot adding LIBS += -lbbdevice to pro file.